# I wanted to create User and Role Entity class but the @Column annotation asks for a data source?

Tags: java

For the @Column names I am getting, assign data source from IntelliJ, I have set up the h2 as my platform and database url. I don't know how to setup this database source.

This is the User Entity class,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

and this is the Role entity class,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure database connections in IntelliJ as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-database-connections.html).

That said you only need to do that if you want IntelliJ to check if table and column names, queries, etc. you put in your code are correct. Not setting datasource in IntelliJ will not affect your application in any way.